# PHP Curl: Send Client-Certificate to Response-Server (Client-Auth)

Tags: php, web-services, curl, ssl, terminal

I'm trying to connect a webservice which requires client-auth.
At first I tried this example: http://www.binarytides.com/use-clientside-ssl-certificate-curl-php/

This doesn't work for me, because:

```
 curl: (58) unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)
```

After that I found an old website from 2005 - http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2005-09/0138.html 
Here you can read that you have to split your PEM-Certificate-File into separate Key- and Cert-Files.
In short: It works!
Now I can do this:

```
 curl -d "param=12345" -G -v --key mykey.pem --cacert mycacert.pem --cert myclientcert:PASSPHRASE https://webservice.xyz
```

But how can I translate this command to a PHP-Script?